# Finding the nth digit of any given number

Tags: python

I'm very new to python, and I'm trying to write a program that will find the nth digit of any given positive integer from the right. How would I go about this? I'm at a bit of a loss as to where I should start. I saw an answer to a similar question suggesting code, and it seemed to work for the op. When I tried it, it just returned the number and specified digit as an ordered pair. This is that code:

```
def get_digit(number, n)
    return number // 10** % 10
```

Comment: Start with a Python tutorial.

Comment: `str(number)[-n]`, checkout [this](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) guide to get started!

Comment: missing `n` in the example: `return (number // 10**n) % 10`. Not sure if this is a typo or what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

This formula will give you the nth digit of a number:

```
def get_digit(number, n): 
     return number // 10**(n-1) % 10 

get_digit(153443, 2)                                                                                                                                                                
# 4
```

or by converting to string:

```
def get_strdigit(num, offset):
   num = str(num)
   return num[offset+1]

get_strdigit(33434324,2)                                                                                                                                                            
# '3'
```